# Showing Dialog from Xib file

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a simple task.

There is a xib file named "Preferences.xib"

It contains Window named "Preferences Window", that contains some checkboxes, OK and Cancel.

I need to load this window within my code, and get Ok/Cancel results knowing what checkboxes were checked.

Can someone help me with example or send me to relevant link?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843016/load-nibs-in-cocoa

Comment: Explanation there is completely insufficient. For example, how should I call for initWithWindowNibName in my case? Preferences? Preferences.xib? Preferences Window? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)showPref:(id)sender;

@property(strong)NSWindowController *windowController;
@property(strong)IBOutlet NSWindow *prefWindow;//hooked to the window of Preferences.XIB

@end
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (IBAction)showPref:(id)sender {
    self.windowController=[[NSWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
    self.prefWindow=self.windowController.window;
    [self.prefWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

[Find sample code here.](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6237101/loadxibprogrammatically-44k?da=y)